# Basic calculations by groups in a dynamic way in R

Tags: r, dplyr, dynamic, calculation

I have a dataset like df with dozens of thousands of observations and +100 categories (in the categorical variables).

This data contains info about different individuals (id) bringing different type of patients to different places for a given price and year.

```
year <- c(2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2010, 2011)
id <- c("A", "A" , "A" , "A" , "A" , "A" , "A", "B", "B")
type <- c("kid", "kid", "adult", "kid", "kid", "dog", "cat", "kid", "kid")
place <- c("hosp", "hosp", "house", "hosp", "hosp", "hosp", "house", "hosp", "hosp")
price <- c(2, 3, 6, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

df <- data.frame(year, id, type, place, price)
```

I want to do **some basic calculations on df** (basically summary statistics) by groups (id-year) in the following manner:

1. create an experience variable by type of patient (assign values according to the number of years that this id has this type)
2. create an experience variable by place (assign values according to the number of years that this id has this place)
3. average price per visit in this given year for each id
4. will the id appear again the following year (t+1)?: this variable can only take values 0 (no), 1 (yes).

So I can get something like **df_new**:

```
year <- c("2010", "2011", "2010", "2011")
id <- c("A", "A", "B", "B")
exp_type_kid <- c(1, 2, 1, 2)
exp_type_adult <- c(1, 1, 0, 0)
exp_type_dog <- c(0, 1, 0, 0)
exp_type_cat <- c(0, 1, 0, 0)
exp_place_hosp <- c(1, 2, 1, 2)
exp_place_house <- c(1, 2, 0, 0)
avg_price <- c(4, 2, 4, 5)
id_repeat_next_year <- c(1, 0, 1, 0)

df_new <- data.frame(year, id, exp_type_kid, exp_type_adult, exp_type_dog, exp_type_cat,
                     exp_place_hosp, exp_place_house, avg_price, id_repeat_next_year)
```

**EDIT**

My dataset can contain much more years, as in the following example:

```
year <- c(2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2009, 2010, 2015, 2017)
id <- c("A", "A" , "A" , "A" , "A" , "A" , "A", "B", "B", "B", "B")
type <- c("kid", "kid", "adult", "kid", "kid", "dog", "cat", "kid", "kid", "kid", "kid")
place <- c("hosp", "hosp", "house", "hosp", "hosp", "hosp", "house", "hosp", "hosp", "hosp", "hosp")
price <- c(2, 3, 6, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4)

df <- data.frame(year, id, type, place, price)
```

Comment: Are those values  in the expected correct

Comment: Yes. Exp_ stands for "experience with...". Therefore it can only be 0,1, or 2 years

Comment: @akrun 0,1,2 in this specific case. My original dataset contains 15 different years, so this variable in my original dataset has a range (0:15)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the `year` to make it `numeric`.

```r
year <- c(2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2011, 2011)
id <- c("A", "A" , "A" , "A" , "A" , "A" , "A")
type <- c("kid", "kid", "adult", "kid", "kid", "dog", "cat")
place <- c("hosp", "hosp", "house", "hosp", "hosp", "hosp", "house")
price <- c(2, 3, 6, 5, 1, 2, 3)

df <- data.frame(year, id, type, place, price)

df
```

```
##   year id  type place price
## 1 2010  A   kid  hosp     2
## 2 2010  A   kid  hosp     3
## 3 2010  A adult house     6
## 4 2010  A   kid  hosp     5
## 5 2011  A   kid  hosp     1
## 6 2011  A   dog  hosp     2
## 7 2011  A   cat house     3
```

I see three different tasks. Points 1 and 2 are about *counting*, point 3
about *aggregating* and point 4 *satisfying a condition*. I think each task must
be addressed individually and hopefully we can merge the results into the
desired `data.frame`.

### Counting experience

For a single factor we can use `table()` to get the counts by year:

```r
with(df, table(year, type))
```

```
##       type
## year   adult cat dog kid
##   2010     1   0   0   3
##   2011     0   1   1   1
```

Now we only care about wether there is an ocurrence of each type for any given
year:

```r
with(df, table(year, type) > 0)
```

```
##       type
## year   adult   cat   dog  kid
##   2010  TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE
##   2011 FALSE  TRUE  TRUE TRUE
```

From here we can `cumsum()` by columns to get the *years of experience*, and
easily turn that into a `data.frame`:

```r
# type
with(df, table(year, type) > 0) |> apply(2, cumsum) |> as.data.frame()
```

```
##      adult cat dog kid
## 2010     1   0   0   1
## 2011     1   1   1   2
```

```r
# place
with(df, table(year, place) > 0) |> apply(2, cumsum) |> as.data.frame()
```

```
##      hosp house
## 2010    1     1
## 2011    2     2
```

Let's turn this into a function to make things easier to follow:

```r
experience_by = function (df, what) {
  out = with(df, table(year, get(what)) > 0) |> apply(2, cumsum) |> as.data.frame()
  names(out) = paste('exp', what, names(out), sep = '_')
  return(out)
}

experience_by(df, 'type')
```

```
##      exp_type_adult exp_type_cat exp_type_dog exp_type_kid
## 2010              1            0            0            1
## 2011              1            1            1            2
```

```r
experience_by(df, 'place')
```

```
##      exp_place_hosp exp_place_house
## 2010              1               1
## 2011              2               2
```

We are missing the `year` variable here (they are `rownames` now) but that will
get solved in the next step.

### Aggregating prices

This is the easy part:

```r
aggregate(price ~ year, FUN = mean, data = df)
```

```
##   year price
## 1 2010     4
## 2 2011     2
```

### Will `id` be present next year?

```r
with(df, unique(year + 1) %in% unique(year)) |> as.numeric()
```

```
## [1] 1 0
```

### Put it all together

```r
experience_by = function (df, what) {
  out = with(df, table(year, get(what)) > 0) |> apply(2, cumsum) |> as.data.frame()
  names(out) = paste('exp', what, names(out), sep = '_')
  return(out)
}

by_type = experience_by(df, 'type')
by_place = experience_by(df, 'place')
avg_price = aggregate(price ~ year, FUN = mean, data = df)
id_repeat_next_year = with(df, as.numeric(unique(year + 1) %in% unique(year)))

cbind(avg_price, by_type, by_place, id_repeat_next_year)
```

```
##      year price exp_type_adult exp_type_cat exp_type_dog exp_type_kid
## 2010 2010     4              1            0            0            1
## 2011 2011     2              1            1            1            2
##      exp_place_hosp exp_place_house id_repeat_next_year
## 2010              1               1                   1
## 2011              2               2                   0
```

For the whole dataset this should be `lapply`ed over the `split`ed `data.frame`.
Something of this sort:

```r
split(df, ~ id) |>
lapply(function (x) {
  by_type = experience_by(df, 'type')
  by_place = experience_by(df, 'place')
  avg_price = aggregate(price ~ year, FUN = mean, data = df)
  id_repeat_next_year = with(df, as.numeric(unique(year + 1) %in% unique(year)))

  cbind(avg_price, by_type, by_place, id_repeat_next_year)
})
```

```
## $A
##      year price exp_type_adult exp_type_cat exp_type_dog exp_type_kid
## 2010 2010     4              1            0            0            1
## 2011 2011     2              1            1            1            2
##      exp_place_hosp exp_place_house id_repeat_next_year
## 2010              1               1                   1
## 2011              2               2                   0
```

From here it should be easy to recover `id`s from the list and `rbind` all
`data.frames`. I am not sure how to fill in values when there are more `id`s
that do not share the same `type`s or `place`s, since this will originate
differing number of columns on each `data.frame`...

---

#### EDIT:

With the new data frame and a new `id`:

```r
year <- c(2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2010, 2011)
id <- c("A", "A" , "A" , "A" , "A" , "A" , "A", "B", "B")
type <- c("kid", "kid", "adult", "kid", "kid", "dog", "cat", "kid", "kid")
place <- c("hosp", "hosp", "house", "hosp", "hosp", "hosp", "house", "hosp", "hosp")
price <- c(2, 3, 6, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

df <- data.frame(year, id, type, place, price)

# use `local()` instead of pipes; `x` instead of `df`
df_new = local({
  dfs = split(df, ~ id)
  dfl = lapply(dfs, function (x) {
    by_type = experience_by(x, 'type')
    by_place = experience_by(x, 'place')
    avg_price = aggregate(price ~ year, FUN = mean, data = x)
    id_repeat_next_year = with(x, as.numeric(unique(year + 1) %in% unique(year)))
  
    cbind(avg_price, by_type, by_place, id_repeat_next_year)
  })

  # recover `id`s
  new_id = rep(names(dfl), times = sapply(dfl, FUN = nrow))

  # create missing cols and combine `dfl`
  all_cols = sapply(dfl, FUN = names) |> unlist() |> unique()
  out = data.frame()
  for (i in dfl) {
    col_present = all_cols %in% names(i)
    if (!all(col_present)) {
      for (cl in all_cols[!col_present]) {
        i[[cl]] = numeric(nrow(i))
      }
    }
  out = rbind(out, i)
  }
  out = data.frame(id = new_id, out, row.names = NULL)
  out
})

df_new
```

```
##   id year price exp_type_adult exp_type_cat exp_type_dog exp_type_kid
## 1  A 2010     4              1            0            0            1
## 2  A 2011     2              1            1            1            2
## 3  B 2010     4              0            0            0            1
## 4  B 2011     5              0            0            0            2
##   exp_place_hosp exp_place_house id_repeat_next_year
## 1              1               1                   1
## 2              2               2                   0
## 3              1               0                   1
## 4              2               0                   0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, your result is not grouped by id. In the mock example id=="A", but might be more ids, so I need to get the result by id. Which part of your code might need to be modified for this?

Comment: @vog, the last code block splits the dataset by `id`.

Comment: However, it does not work when you include different id's (see above the data modified when I include another type (B)).

Comment: @vog, works for me, is just that remains 'splited' by `id`. Added code to 'rebind' the data frames.

Comment: The problem is on the values. They are not correct. It assigns the same value to each variable across id's.

Comment: You're right! my bad, had forgot to replace `df` from the first experiments. I edited again, think it is working fine now. Must say that combining again the `data.frames` is really cumbersome, makes me wonder if there is a real need to store this as a single `data.frame`...

Comment: Thanks @Coy. I need all the previous information (lets say, for each year and id). Do you have any idea to make it faster?. Your code works for the example posted. However, it does not work on my dataset (same type of variables but much larger)                                                               ```Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 2, 7
In addition: There were 44 warnings (use warnings() to see them)``` Any idea?

Comment: The problem comes with ```cbind``` in ```dfl```.                                                                             Moreover, if I add more years to the mock data shared before (see extension), a new error appears ```Error in eval(quote({ : 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'```. This new error is associated to the line ```new_id = rep(names(dfl), times = sapply(dfl, FUN = nrow))})```. My dataset collects many years for some individuals. Therefore, I might also face this problems later on.